# how to integrate azure api management to node socket.io application

Tags: azure, websocket, socket.io, gateway, azure-api-management

I am trying to integrate our socket.io application with azure api management. But I am unable to find any solution, whether it is possible or not. Can any one help me OR give me some suggestions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**UPDATE:** WebSockets are now [supported in APIM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/websocket-api). Currently, only passthrough is supported which creates a one-to-one mapping of the connection between the client and APIM, and the connection between APIM and the backend websocket server. Also, do note the [limitations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/websocket-api#limitations) that exist today.

Thanks @restfulhead for the bringing this up here

---

Unfortunately, WebSockets are not supported in Azure API Management as of today. There is a feature request on [UserVoice](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/248703-api-management/suggestions/6060419-socket-full-duplex-support-in-addition-to-http) which you could up vote to gain more traction.

Today, for WebSocket applications, you can use [Azure Application Gateway](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/overview) which [supports websockets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/application-gateway-websocket).

On another note, [Azure SignalR](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/services/signalr-service/) is also a great service for building managed, scalable, realtime websocket-powered applications ***but*** is more of an alternative to `socket.io` in NodeJS for C#.

Comment: So, if I use socket.io with transporter as websocket, then shall we use Azure Application Gateway..?

Comment: Yes. Azure Application Gateway is the best candidate for the job.

Comment: Web Sockets are now supported by APIM: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/updates/public-preview-native-support-for-websocket-apis-in-azure-api-management/